# C# Run same query multiple times to check if anything returned

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that I want to check if something returns.  The goal is to have nothing returned and I want to retry for 15 seconds if something gets returned.  However I'm having a hard time getting this loop to work properly.  Can anyone suggest fix to this code?  It goes to "SQL table good!" after 2 tries even though the query should have returned something.

```
//SqlDataReader readerPromo = promoTablecmd.ExecuteReader();
var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
//Loop so that if less than 10 seconds, keep retrying SQL cmd above.
while (true)
{
    double elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    SqlDataReader readerPromo = promoTablecmd.ExecuteReader();
    // If query returned something
    if (readerPromo.Read())
    {


        if (elapsedTime > 15000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error found!");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found descrepency in SQL table retrying again for 10 seconds...");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            continue;
        }

    }
    else {

         Console.WriteLine("SQL table good!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `execute reader` inside the loop

Comment: You have to re-execute the query each time you want to check. New results are not automatically streamed to the open reader. So that first line of code should be inside of the loop as you want to execute it on each iteration in the loop.

Comment: I tried that however it keeps giving me There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.  I tried setting "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" in my connection doesn't work.  Please see edited code.

Comment: Correct. You should use a `using` block for your reader to close the reader and possibly the underlying connection depending on the behavior specified when opening the reader. You could leave the connection open although I would not recommend it if this is a long running process especially as ado.net has connection pooling implemented for you so opening a new managed connection is relatively cheap.

Comment: `promoTablecmd.ExecuteScalar()` would obviate the need for a reader altogether. All you want to know here is whether there is at least one result, you don't need a reader

Answer (score 1):

Using async here is more correct. This should work:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Repro()
    {
        var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();//mock
        using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));//timeout after 15 seconds
        await WaitEndOfDataAsync(sqlCmd, cts.Token, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));//setting check interval
    }

    private static async Task WaitEndOfDataAsync(SqlCommand cmd, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan checkInterval)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            using(var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                var hasData = await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await reader.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (!hasData)
                    return;
            }
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            await Task.Delay(checkInterval, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

It will loop through data, and if timeout reached - throws OperationCancelledException.